# Prove/Disprove: For any sets $X$ and $Y$, $\overline{X\cap Y} = \bar{X}\cup\bar{Y}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove/Disprove: For any sets $X$ and $Y$, $\overline{X\cap Y} = \bar{X}\cup\bar{Y}$

Extra question in my proofs homework, similar to another question I posted, but not exactly the same I don't think. How would I start with this?

Comment: Demorgan's law? If not just show that they are subsets of each other.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: look up DeMorgan's Laws. That's all there is to it. In fact, I'll do the looking-it-up for you:

The laws are that $$\overline{A \cup B} = \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$$
$$\overline{A \cap B} = \overline{A} \cup \overline{B} $$

And [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeMorgan%27s_Law#Formal_proof) is a formal proof. Note that $\overline{A}$ is often also written $A^c$. You can also just Google for it --- proofs of DeMorgan's Laws are a dime a dozen on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

An arbitrary object $x$ is element of the class $\overline{X\cap Y}$ iff it is not in the set $X\cap Y$, iff it is not in both $X$ and $Y$, iff it not in $X$ or not in $Y$, ...

Answer (score 2):

This is just DeMorgan's Law for sets. The way we can prove this is if we show that each is a subset of one another.

We first assume that some arbitrary x $\in \overline{X\cap Y}$ and show that x $\in \overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}$. If x $\in \overline{X\cap Y}$ then x $\notin$ X or x $\notin$ Y.

Case #1: Say that x $\notin$ X, then x $\in \bar{X}$ and thus x $\in \overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}$.

Case #2: Say that x $\notin$ Y, then x $\in \bar{Y}$ and thus x $\in \overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}$.

This completes the proof that $\overline{X\cap Y}$ $\subset$ $\overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}$.

We now show that if x $\in \overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}$ then x $\in \overline{X\cap Y}$. If x $\in \overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}$ then either x $\in \overline{X}$ or x $\in \overline{Y}$.

Case #1: Say x $\in \overline{X}$. Then x is $\notin$ X. Then x $\in \overline{X\cap Y}$ since if x isn't in X then it can't be in the intersection of X and some other set Y. Thus, it $is$ a member of the complement of the intersection of X and Y.

Case #2: Say x $\in \overline{Y}$. Then x is $\notin$ Y. Then x $\in \overline{X\cap Y}$ since if x isn't in Y then it can't be in the intersection of some set X and Y. Thus, it $is$ a member of the complement of the intersection of X and Y.

This shows that $\overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}$ $\subset$ $\overline{X\cap Y}$.

Since both sets are subsets of one another, we have shown that the two are equivalent. So we have shown that $\overline{X\cap Y}$ = $\overline{X} \cup \overline{Y}$.

Hope that helps.

:)

Answer (score 1):

Transforming into logic gets it easily
$\forall x(x \not\in X\cap Y)\iff \forall x((x \not\in X)\lor(x \not\in Y))\\
\forall x(\neg(x \in X\cap Y)\iff \forall x(\neg(x \in X)\lor\neg(x \in Y))\\
\forall x(\neg(x\in X\land x \in Y) \iff \forall x(\neg(x \in X)\lor\neg(x \in Y))\\
p=\tau(x \in X),q=\tau(x \in Y)\\\neg(p\land q)\iff (\neg p\lor \neg q)$
And proofing that this is a tautology is pretty easy.